# Why did two old answers just show up in the review queue as Late Answers?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, answers, review-queue

These two answers by the same user:

1. [Is selling your house without an agent worth the hassle?](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/6187)
2. [Recent college grad. Down payment on a house or car?](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/6186)

just showed up in the Late Answers review queue; I wondered how a user with 1 point could post an answer on a protected question, when I noticed that the answers had been posted in 2011. The answers didn't show up as [new answers to old questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions), so is this a bug in the review queue or some nuance I'm unaware of?

Chris just deleted [two](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/10791/7590) [answers](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/11277/7590) by this user. Perhaps that's relevant.

Comment: That particular account recently (very recently) lost quite a few points in a recalculation.  I wonder if other mod actions triggered the queue?

Comment: @MrChrister I presume the recalculation is only something moderators can see? I don't see anything in [the user's reputation tab](http://money.stackexchange.com/users/4624/carlita-menezes?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: Correct.  That information you linked is almost exactly the same.  The recalculation was all those answers being deleted.

Comment: @MrChrister Good to know; looking at the reputation tab again, I can visibly tell that something has happened, because 10+10+10+... +20 != 1.

Comment: I deleted some of that account's answers by flagging as spam. Spam flags resulting in answer deletion reduce reputation by 100. Thus, the account is at 1 rep (minimum) despite having two surviving answers at +2 and +4 votes.  Sometimes spammers post non-link-containing answers to other questions, as red herrings to throw us off the spammy scent of their other answers.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I figured something like that was the case with the reputation; did the other answers show up in the review queue because of the spam flags (sort of as a reminder for someone to review them again)?

Comment: @JohnBensin I'm speculating, but given the new rep = 1, the answers are likely in the review queue now because they were never reviewed in the first place. The answers may have been exempt from review based on the reputation at the time they were posted.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Ah, that sounds plausible. I didn't realize that was a feature, but it makes perfect sense in hindsight.

Comment: I just saw another answer pop into the queue that's 4 years old: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/what-are-binary-options